# Adding a component in React results in horizontal scroll bar

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

Here's the website before adding the `Navbar` component:
[image: Before new component]

and here's the website after adding the new component:
[image]

I have no idea what properties are causing this, but here's the code:

**index.js**

```
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
    import './index.css';
    import App from './App';
    
    
    // React entry point
    const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
    root.render(
      <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
      </React.StrictMode>
    );
```

**index.css**

```css
    /* tailwind directives */
    @tailwind base;
    @tailwind components;
    @tailwind utilities;
    
    
    body,
    html {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif !important;
    }
```

**App.js**

```
    import { ChakraProvider } from '@chakra-ui/react';
    import Welcome from './components/Welcome';
    import Navbar from './components/Navbar'
    
    
    // Main React component
    export default function App() {
      return (
        <ChakraProvider>
          <div className="App w-screen">
            <Welcome />
            <Navbar />
          </div>
        </ChakraProvider>
      );
    }
```

**Welcome.js**

```
    import "./Welcome.css"
    import React from "react";
    
    
    // Welcome section
    export default function Welcome() {
    
        return (
            <div className="Welcome w-screen h-screen grid place-items-center">
                <div className="Welcome-content grid place-items-center space-y-10 text-white">
                    <p className="Welcome-text text-center ">
                        Hello, I'm <span className="Welcome-name text-emerald-400">Omar El Atyqy</span>.
                        <br />
                        I'm a <span className="Welcome-job text-emerald-400 txt-rotate" data-period="1000"
                            data-rotate='[ "web developper", "data scientist", "passionate geek" ]'></span>.
                    </p>
                    <a href="#" className="Welcome-button hover:bg-emerald-500 py-4 px-6">
                        Let's have a look!
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

**welcome.css**

```css
    .Welcome {
        background-image: url("../../public/images/background.png");
    }
    
    .Welcome-text {
        font-size: 32pt;
        line-height: 36pt;
        font-weight: 400;
    }
    
    .Welcome-button {
        font-size: 15pt;
        border: 2px solid #fff;
        transition-duration: 0.5s;
    }
```

**Navbar.js**

```
    import './Navbar.css'
    
    
    export default function Navbar () {
        return (
            <div className='Navbar w-screen'>
                hello world
            </div>
        );
    }
```

I haven't included `App.css` and `Navbar.css` because they are empty.

Comment: What should happen instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `w-screen`, the navbar and welcome components will have a with of `100vw`. Which is exactly the with of the viewport. You have set `h-screen` on the welcome component, so that one will fill the viewport completely. Now if you add the navbar, the height of the total page will exceed the hight of the viewprot, so it will add a sidebar on the right. This makes the actual area to fit the components in smaller, so your components are to wide for the window, that’s why the vertical scroll bar appears.

You can fix this by replacing `w-screen` with `w-full`, which makes components take 100% of the available space, rather than fixed width based on the width of the viewport.

See the different [descriptions of the classes in the tailwind docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/width).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the browser debug, if you are using chrome, press F12, after opening, press CTRL + SHIFT + C or select the pointer in the upper left corner and hover over the element, check what is causing this, because this way, it is very complicated to debug and understand

Comment: try adding `overflow-x: hidden` to body in your css

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `margin: 0` and `box-sizing: border-box` in App.css ?
By default, div elements might have `margin: 1rem` or kind of stuff so if you set your container element to take full width, its content might overflow and causes a slider.

So `App.css` file will look like this.

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: @omar-el-atyqy this is probably the fix you need. I'm also guessing you might want you navbar to be positioned at the top of your page so you might want to consider position absolute or fixed.